# How to make mapped input files to rerender after calling setState into its origin array?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I recently got started with React and went straight into NextJs. I'm building a Form with some input files, similar to this example I made in codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/base-web-stateful-uncontrolled-usage-forked-5b1d9?file=/src/example.js

The problem is that if you set a file in the 2nd input file (or any but the last) and then remove it with the button, it rerenders the list but doesnt reloads the input's content (the file is still there on the UI).

I don't know if my approach is good or where I'm doing wrong. Could you please help me with this?

Comment: You're using the `index` of your mapped function as a `key` - this isn't good enough. It needs to be unique so that React can tell the difference between sibling components and update the DOM correctly. See [the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) and [this article](https://robinpokorny.medium.com/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318).

Comment: @lawrence-witt Thanks a lot! That was it, I had no idea! I don't see the button to mark your answer as the accepted one :(
I think you should answer the question itself instead of commenting